# Logs with exponential bases

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I know that $e^{\log_{e^2} (16)}$ is 4, but I can only get this far:

$$e^{\log_{e^2}(4^2)}$$
$$e^{2\log_{e^2}(4)}$$

I need some way to cancel the 2's so I can get

$$e^{\log_e(4)}$$

but I don't the identity or rule that cancels the 2's.

Comment: "cancel out the 2s":  You don't.    Let $b = e^2$ then $e^{2*{\log_{e^2}4}}=({e^2})^{\log_{(e^2)}4}= b^{\log_b 4}$. No canceling needed

Answer (score 1):

$$\exp{\log_{e^2}(16)} = \exp\frac{\log{16}}{\log(e^2)} = \exp\frac{\log{16}}{2} = \exp{\log(16^{1/2})} = 16^{1/2} = 4.$$

I used the following rules: $\log_a(x) = \frac{\log(x)}{\log(a)}$, and $c\log(x) = \log(x^c)$.

Comment: Thanks. In the rule you applied, is it log base10 of 16 / log base 10 of e^2?

Comment: @theBIOguy I use log to base $e$, when my logs don't have a subscript. So when I apply the rule, it's $\log_e(16)/\log_e(e^2)$. And $\log_e(e^2)=2$, because $2$ is exactly the number you raise $e$ to to get $e^2$.

Comment: Can be log based anything.  I'm assuming HowDoIMath is using the very common, but slightly misleading, log = log base e = ln notation.  $\log = \log_{10}$ is utterly arbitrary and past high school *no* mathematician uses it.  (I don't know about physical scientists.)  $\log =\ln$ is *very* common though.  I try to avoid ambiguity by either never using $\log$ or only using it in cases where the base could be anything.  (As in the statement $\log_b a = \frac {\log a}{\log b}$; it's true for any base.)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about "cancelling".

$b^{n *\log_{b^n} x} = (b^n)^{\log_{(b^n)} x} = x$

====

$e^{\log_{e^2}16}= e^{\log_{e^2}4^2}= e^{2*{\log_{e^2}4}}=({e^2})^{\log_{(e^2)}4}=4$

Or better yet:

$e^{\log_{e^2}16} =e^{\frac {\ln 16}{\ln e^2}} = e^{\frac {\ln 2^4}{2}}=e^{\frac {4\ln 2}{2}} = e^{2\ln 2} = (e^{\ln 2})^2 =2^2 = 4$

Or....$e^{\log_{e^2}16} =e^{\frac {\ln 16}{\ln e^2}} = e^{\frac {\ln 4^2}{2}}=e^{\frac {2\ln 4}{2}} = e^{\ln 4} = 4$.

Etc. etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting. How do you cancel the 2's?

Comment: $\log_b x^a = a \log_b x$.  $a^{bc} = (a^b)c$ and $\log_b  b^n = n$.  Use all three to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Let's reason out what the expression for the exponent represents.  That is, denote

$$
q = \log_{e^2} 16
$$

This is equivalent to

$$
(e^2)^q = 16
$$

Since, in general for positive $a, b, c, (a^b)^c = a^{bc} = (a^c)^b$, this becomes

$$
(e^q)^2 = 16
$$

or finally

$$
e^q = 4
$$

where we can eliminate $e^q = -4$ because for real $q$, $e^q$ is necessarily positive.  And we're done!

Comment: Thank you all. I was looking for a rule and the answer was basic algebra. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking about "cancelling the 2s", try it this way:  You can write $e^{2\log_{e^2}(4)}$ as $(e^2)^{log_{e^2}(4)}$.  Now use the fact that for *any* base $b$, $b^{\log_b(x)}=x$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula for logarithms $$\log_{a^q}b=\tfrac1q \log_ab$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a^x=y$; then
$$
x\log a=\log y
$$
(the unadorned $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm). This means that
$$
\log_a x=\frac{\log y}{\log a}
$$
by definition of $\log_a$. Therefore
$$
\log_{e^2}16=\frac{\log 16}{\log e^2}=\frac{2\log 4}{2}=\log 4
$$
and finally
$$
e^{\log_{e^2}16}=e^{\log 4}=4
$$